# SQL Query after migrate from PostgreSQL to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, select, where-clause

Recently, I migrated my postgreSQL database to MongoDB. Let say I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL and migrated become 2 collections in MongoDB.
In PostgreSQL:

1. Table accountCode

   | ac_id | desc | group_id | p_code | c_code |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 999.01 | PettyCash | 9 | 42000 | 99000 |
   | 888.09 | Tax | 34 | 70000 | 66000 |
   | 999.02 | PC2 | 9 | 43000 | 99000 |
2. Table transaction

   | reffNum | ac_id | db | cr | desc | dateTime | id | audited |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | GL/0003845/V/11/21/XXX | 999.01 | 950000 | 0 | Transfer from Client | 2021-03-17 09:58:41.304302 | 2 | 0 |
   | GL/0005584/V/11/21/XXX | 999.02 | 10000 | 0 | Transfer from Client | 2021-03-18 09:58:41.304302 | 2 | 0 |
   | SL/00077898/V/11/21/XXX | 888.09 | 997500 | 0 | Tax | 2021-03-18 09:58:41.304302 | 2 | 0 |
   | GL/0005485/V/11/21/XXX | 999.01 | 0 | 150000 | Transfer to Client | 2021-03-25 09:58:41.304302 | 3 | 0 |

And I have SQL Query like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SUM (A .db) - SUM (A .cr)) is NULL  THEN '0' ELSE (SUM (A .db) - SUM (A .cr)) END from transaction a, accountCode b
where a.ac_id = b.ac_id and a.id<>0 AND (a.audited='0') AND to_char(a.dateTime,'YYYY-MM') = '2021-03' AND b.groupid="9"
```

And it should give result: 810000

I was migrate the DB to 2 collections in MongoDB, similar with 2 tables in PostgreSQL. But now, I'm confuse how to query so I have same result in MongoDB? Or should I change the structure from 2 tables to just 1 single collection in MongoDB? Any thought? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You can join two collections by using $lookup(Aggregation)

```
{$lookup:
 {
   from: <collection to join>,
   localField: <field from the input documents>,
   foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
   as: <output array field>
 }}
```

> **But it is recommended to create both tables as a single collection Mongodb is meant to use like that.**